# A circle wheel 28 inches in diameter rotates (moves) the same number of inches per second

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A circle wheel 28 inches in diameter rotates (moves) the same number of inches per second as a circular wheel 35 inches in diameter. If the smaller wheel makes x revolutions per second, how many revolutions per minute does the larger wheel make in terms of x?

Comment: how many inches does the smaller wheel move per second? If big wheel makes $y$ revolutions per sec, how many inches does it move? Equate and find answer.

Answer (score 2):

circumference * (rev/min) of 28 =circumference * (rev/min) of 35

to calculate $z$

$$\pi \cdot 28 \cdot x=\pi \cdot 35 \cdot z$$

$$z=\frac{4}{5} \cdot x$$
(but this is inch/sec we want inch/min)

$$z=\frac{4}{5} \cdot x \cdot 60 =48x$$

Comment: yes akash.you done the write job.in the last phase you multiply x by 60.is 60 means 60 sec

Comment: you have to convert the total number of inches in a second to inches in a minute. So, you must calculate it for 60 seconds. Thus, multiply it with 60. JOB done!!